# Is this how we create a structural object hierarchy (object model) like Excel VBA?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to learn how to create an object hierarchy (like that of excel vba).
I have written some code and want to ask if this is the right way to go. Also, I want to know if creating this type of object structure will have any significant effect on performance. I will access the objects as for e.g. this way :

```
Hotel hotel = new Hotel();

int x = hotel.Rooms[1].Count; // just an example

int y = hotel.Rooms.Room.Count; // just an example

    class Hotel
    {
        private int i;
        public Hotel()
        {
            i = 10; // some prossessing to give the value of i. Lets say 10
        }
        public _Rooms Rooms
        {
            get { return new _Rooms(i); }
        }
    }
    class _Rooms
    {
        private int _i;
        public _Rooms(int i)
        {
            this._i = i;
        }
        public _Room this[int i]
        {
            get { return new _Room(_i); }
        }

        public _Room Room // _Room Property
        {
            get { return new _Room(this._i); }
        }
    }
    class _Room
    {
        private int _i;
        public _Room(int i)
        {
            // some prossessing to give the value of i. Lets say :
            _i = i + 10;
        }
        public int Count
        {

            get { _i = 15; return _i; }
        }
    }
```

***This is just a simple example of the model that I want to achieve.***

Comment: What does `_Root.Count` mean? You don't need `_Rooms` either. You can just expose a `Rooms` property in `Hotel` of some list/array type, or you can have a plain indexer instead. You almost never need to create custom collection types unless the collection does extra processing or bookkeeping.

Comment: If you wan a code review, you better post request to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/